# Syntax of loops

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to iterate a URL to scrape. What am I missing in my syntax?

```
array = [1...100]

array.each do |i|
    a = 'http://www.web.com/page/#{i}/'.scrapify(images: [:png, :gif, :jpg])
    extract_images(a[:images])
end
```

Comment: It wont find my url...something is wrong in the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array = [1...100]` doesn't do what you think it does. That creates an array with a single element and that single element is a [`Range`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Range.html) instance whose first value is `1` and whose last value is `99`.

So, after sorting out your string interpolation problem (as noted [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25944177/479863)), this:

```
"http://www.web.com/page/#{i}/"
```

will be the string:

```
"http://www.web.com/page/1...100/"
```

and the remote server probably doesn't know what that means and it will either 404 or give you page one; your comments elsewhere suggest that it will give you page one and ignore the `...100` part of the URL.

If you want it loop from `1` to `99` then you'd say:

```
(1...100).each do |i|
  # `i` will range from 1 to 99 in this block
end
```

If you want to loop from `1` to `100` you'd use `..` instead of `...`:

```
(1..100).each do |i|
  # `i` will range from 1 to 100 in this block
end
```

You could also ditch the range completely and use [`times`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html#method-i-times):

```
99.times do |i|
  # `i` will range from 0 to 98 in this block so
  # you'd work with `i+1`
end

100.times do |i|
  # `i` will range from 0 to 99 in this block so
  # you'd work with `i+1`
end
```

or [`upto`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html#method-i-upto) (thanks to [JKillian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3124288/jkillian) for the reminder about this one):

```
1.upto(99) do |i|
  # `i` will range from 1 to 99 in this block
end

1.upto(100) |i|
  # `i` will range from 1 to 100 in this block
end
```

Comment: I personally like [`1.upto(99)`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Integer.html#method-i-upto) because it seems the most clear to me. Nevertheless, this is the best answer because it address all the issues of the OP

Comment: @JKillian: I think `upto` probably would be the best one, thanks for the reminder. I rarely do this sort of loop in Ruby, I find `each_with_index` or `with_index` to be more common.

Answer (score 2):

For interpolation you should use double quotes(`" "` instead `' '`):

```
array = [1...100]

array.each do |i|
    a = "http://www.web.com/page/#{i}/".scrapify(images: [:png, :gif, :jpg])
    extract_images(a[:images])
end
```

Comment: Still wont find the URL, strange!

Comment: not sure but try remove trailing slash `/` from url.

Comment: Ok worked. It was because the page didn't have 100 pages, so it wouldnt find it. You were right. Thanks!